# Countability of a set given countability of a set operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm sorry to bother since I suppose my problem is pretty easy to find an answer to, I just can't find anything in gogle, or better, I'm not really sure how to google my problem.

I'm studying for my Discrete Math Exam, and an old question (don't have the solutions) goes as follows:

The Set $A\setminus B$ is countable. Set $A$ is uncountable. What conclusion can you draw about the un/countability of $B$?

I've been trying to apply the properties of in/sur/bijections but it's too general to be applied here. It must be some set operation rule I'm missing that I can't find.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The proof is already given in an answer, but to just think about it intuitively: $A$ has a "very-huge" number of elements, and removing the elements of $B$ from that leaves a "less-huge" number of elements, so the size of $B$ is probably... (Admittedly, infinities often don't match our intuitions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$. So, since $A$ is uncountable and $A\setminus B$ is countable, $A\cap B$ has to be uncountable, and therefore $B$ has to be uncountable.

Comment: Well what can I say, putting it that way it makes complete sense. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help.